# What is the movement of the material point?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, kinematics

The parametric formulas for movement of a material point are:

$x(t) = A \sin (kt)$

$y(t) = B(1 - \sin(kt))$

Describe the movement of the MP.

That is the entire question and I can't find a solution. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that Physics.StackExchange is *not* a homework help site. Please [see this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093)

Comment: Have you tried actually working the problem out, rather than trying to find a solution elsewhere?

Comment: @KyleKanos I have tried to solve it and didn't know where else to go.

Comment: Put k=A=B=1, then compute x and y for values of t from 0 to $2\pi$. Plot them. Repeat with A=2. What do you notice? Now generalize.

Comment: @Floris I have drawn the trajectory but I'm not sure how I would describe it. It returs back to where it was on X and it grows on Y following a pattern (B * [1 0 1 2 1]).

Comment: Unless you wrote the equation wrong, it should return to the same Y value as well (is there a $t$ missing?), and the movement will will be a straight line with a (negative) slope equal to -B/A. And since the point is accelerating and decelerating, it describes simple harmonic motion about the point (0, B) with a frequency k.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have enough reputation to comment. but why do not just eliminate $sin(kt)$ as a variable and see what equation is left for $x$ vs $y$ ?

To answer the question in the comment:
$sin(kt)=x/A$

Then replacing on the second equation you get:

$y=B(1-x/A)$

which is the equation of a straight line.

Of course, once you know that you want to analyze how it moves across time, but Floris already answered that in his comment

Comment: why the minus one?

Comment: How does one "eliminate $\sin(kt)$ as a variable"?

Comment: are u sure it's a straight line? because doing what @Floris sugested doesn't look like a straight line

Comment: yes, I am pretty sure, just look at the equation (I assume you know the equation of a straight line).

Comment: Yes it is a straight line - unless you didn't write the equation down properly...

Comment: Hi David, please don't answer homework questions.  It encourages users to ask them even though they're explicitly off-topic.

Comment: @BrandonEnright I only gave a hint, but then Kyle Kanos   asked for more details.

Comment: @DavidLynch: I misread the question, I thought it said $x(t)\sim\cos(kt)$ which would have made "eliminating" the sine term quite difficult. But, as Brandon says, answering zero-effort HW questions is a bad idea because it encourages more of them. Please see [this Meta post](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/) about homework questions for more information.

Comment: @KyleKanos, it ok. I just wanted to write a comment for that same reason, a hint. But at the time I didn't have enough reputation